# Is there a way to exclude Properties marked with [Obsolete] Attribute from .BeEquivalentTo(..) in FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I test equivalence of custom clones of instances by checking them with .Should().BeEquivalentTo(..) from FluentAssertions.
Now there are Properties which are marked as Obsolete and do not get cloned anymore. Is there a Way to exclude such properties?

I tried to get the propertie's Attributes but failed.

```
.Excluding(b => b.SelectedMemberInfo.MemberType.GetCustomAttributesData()
                  .Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(ObsoleteAttribute)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `MemberType` gives you the type of object exposed by the field or property, but not the property or field itself (the .NET `MemberInfo`, `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`). You can work around that by using a rather ugly construct like this:

`Excluding(b => b.SelectedMemberInfo.DeclaringType.GetMember(b.Name).SingleOrDefault()?.GetCustomAttributes().Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(ObsoleteAttribute))`

Comment: I endet up using `.Excluding(a => a.DeclaringType.GetMember(a.Name).SingleOrDefault().GetCustomAttributesData().Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(ObsoleteAttribute)))` which deviates in one `SelectedMemberInfo` at the beginning. I guess because `a` is allready the `SelectedMemberInfo` ?